# How to remove maximize button in Mac OS X tool window in Qt

Tags: macos, qt

I have a floating tool window. It works fine on Windows, but I can't get 
rid of the maximise button on Mac OS X. I have tried unsetting 
`Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint` and setting the window to fixed size. 
Nothing seems to work.

```
MyWidget::MyWidget( QWidget* parent )
:QWidget( parent, Qt::Tool | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint )
{
   setupUi( this );

   setFixedSize( sizeHint() ); // doesn't remove maximise button
   setWindowFlags( windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint ); // doesn't remove maximise button
}
```

I don't want to use a frameless window. Any ideas? I am using Qt 4.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code from Richard Gustavsen of Nokia works in Qt 4.4:

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
    public:

    MyWidget::MyWidget( QWidget* parent ) : QWidget(parent, Qt::Tool)
    {
    }

    void setVisible(bool visible)
    {
        QWidget::setVisible(visible);
        ChangeWindowAttributes(qt_mac_window_for(this), kWindowNoAttributes, kWindowFullZoomAttribute);
    }
};
```

Thanks Richard and Nokia!

Comment: Why can't I find ChangeWindowAttributes with qt 4.8 64 bit build？

Answer (score 10):

Launch Qt windowflags example application. Choose `Tool` radio button and then check:

- Window title
- Customize window
- Window close button

It's the only way I found on Mac OS X to achieve what you want BUT you will loose minimize button. There's no other way. That's Mac OS X Window Manager limitation.

Summarizing, there are only five sets of buttons in title bar:

1. All buttons visible and all buttons enabled: `setWindowFlags(Qt::Tool)`
2. All buttons visible, close and maximize buttons enabled, minimize button disabled: `setWindowFlags(Qt::Tool
   | Qt::WindowTitleHint
   | Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint
   | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint
   | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint)`
3. All buttons visible, maximize button enabled, close and minimize disabled: `setWindowFlags(Qt::Tool
   | Qt::WindowTitleHint
   | Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint
   | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint)`
4. Only close button is visible and enabled `setWindowFlags(Qt::Tool | Qt::WindowTitleHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint)`
5. No buttons in title bar: `setWindowFlags(Qt::Tool | Qt::WindowTitleHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint)`

Comment: Kamil,

Great answer. Unfortunately it seems that Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint is not available in Qt 4.4!

Comment: Sorry for that but I'm currently using Qt 4.6, but my intention was to make you run windowflags example from Qt, so you could easily and quite fast try most options

Comment: I've tried the windowflags example in Qt 4.4, but couldn't find a combination that removed the maximize button.

Comment: This doesn't work in Qt 5.11 at least. Option #4 on macOS still shows a maximize button.

Answer (score 3):

You could try setting the window flag to include `Qt::Dialog` (bold added):

> Indicates that the widget is a window that should be decorated as a dialog (i.e., **typically no maximize or minimize buttons in the title bar**). This is the default type for QDialog. If you want to use it as a modal dialog, it should be launched from another window, or have a parent and used with the QWidget::windowModality property. If you make it modal, the dialog will prevent other top-level windows in the application from getting any input. We refer to a top-level window that has a parent as a secondary window.

I don't know what would happen if you tried setting both `Qt::Dialog` and `Qt::Tool`, but it might be worth investigating.

Comment: Tried both Qt::Dialog | Qt::Tool and Qt::Dialog. Still had a maximise button in both cases!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do it with

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::WindowTitleHint | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a cross platform way to do it. You have override your setVisible method of your  QMainWindow or QWidget. The same way any window flag can be modified that has visual impact on the window.

The reason this has to be done this way is that the class needs to have window specs before it actually shows the window.

```
void setVisible(bool visible)
{
    setWindowFlags( windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint );
    QWidget::setVisible(visible);
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer in that it doesn't unset any window flags previously set.